# Azure data factory API

Tags: azure-data-factory

I have constructed a very simple pipeline to test the concept of a pipeline monitoring itself using the REST API, but I am constantly running into 404 Resource not found errors.

here is the general format of my GET request.

https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/_MY SUB_/resourceGroups/*MY_RG*/providers/Microsoft.DataFactory/factories/@{pipeline().DataFactory}/pipelineruns/@{pipeline().RunId}?api-version=2018-06-01

Even using the static try it functionality from learn.microsoft.com using hard coded known values also results in a 404.

The run id being generated from @{pipeline().RunId} matches that seen from the monitor.

Comment: One suggestion from Microsoft was that the pipeline should either be native immediate code or in the main branch of any connected repository. -- To facilitate publishing.
I altered my code branch accordingly but the error 404 still persists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Issue solved.
in ADF you cannot utilize the get run id capability of the REST API on runid's that are from debug runs.
The runID must be from a 'triggered' pipeline.

Comment: Correct.  Debug pipeline runs are considered a different resource than normal pipeline runs.  They are kept in a different endpoint.